# Deleting many duplicate points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, performance, delete

I have a shapefile with more than 6 million points, most of which are identical. I used the built-in tool Delete Identical by using Shape property to do it, which takes almost 10 hours and only complete 20%.

The point shapefile only contains three fields, including ID, x-coordinate and y-coordinate. I want to delete the duplicate records from the existing shapefile based on the condition that the points have same x,y coordinates. I can also save the unique records to another shapefile, depending on which method is much faster.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 Advanced License.

Comment: Do you need to retain the table attributes?

Comment: I only need the shape property, i.e. x,y coordinates, of the unique point.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS?  What are the features stored in (shapefile, file gdb, enterprise gdb)?  Do you want it saved to new feature class or just removed from existing?

Comment: It will ***always*** be faster to write a new 3m row table than to delete 3m rows from a 6m row table.  It would even be faster to write to a temp table, then truncate and copy those rows back into the source table.

Comment: Thanks. Does the "temp table" mean to use "in_memory"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that this script copies unique points into separate originally empty shapefile about 5 times faster, compare to delete identical. I tested it on 200,000 points, with 100,000 of them being a duplicate.

```py
import arcpy, time,os
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteoutput=True
allPoints=r'C:\...\ScratchFolder\POINTs.shp'
outFC=r'C:\...\ScratchFolder\OUTPUT\Block_00000.shp'
curT=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFC,"Shape@")

result=arcpy.GetCount_management(allPoints)
nF=int(result.getOutput(0))

aDict={}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(allPoints, "SHAPE@XY") as cursor:
  arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "", 0, nF,1)
  for row in cursor:
    arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
    v=row[0]
    if aDict.has_key(v):continue
    aDict[v]=1
    curT.insertRow((row[0],))
```

It confirms @Vince point.

Use fastest drive to store input and output, network drives=NO GO.
I suggest to run it from mxd or ArcCatalog, you can watch progress and cancel at any time.

UPDATE TO HANDLE TOLERANCE:

```py
import arcpy, time,os
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteoutput=True

def truncate(f, n):
  s = '{}'.format(f)
  i, p, d = s.partition('.')
  return '.'.join([i, (d+'0'*n)[:n]])        

allPoints=r'C:\...Data\ScratchFolder\POINTs.shp'
outFC=r'C:\...Data\ScratchFolder\OUTPUT\Block_00000.shp'
curT=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFC,"Shape@")
result=arcpy.GetCount_management(allPoints)
nF=int(result.getOutput(0))
aDict={}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(allPoints, "SHAPE@XY") as cursor:
  arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "", 0, nF,1)
  for row in cursor:
    arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
    x,y=row[0]
    v='%s_%s' %(truncate(x,3),truncate(y,3))
    if aDict.has_key(v):continue
    aDict[v]=1
    curT.insertRow((row[0],))
```

This will consider points to be the same if their coordinates are identical to 3 decimal places. I badly want to hope that you at least working with projected data

Comment: Thanks. I am testing it now. By the way, how long did it cost you when you run the 200,000 points?

Comment: 24 seconds compared to about 2 mins with delete identical

Comment: As always it took ArcView 3.2 only 5 seconds to accomplish the same task (including delete !). This is why I keep it in my pocket. Not sure how long it will take with your set... ArcGIS performance on geometries is very-very far from perfect

Comment: Would DeleteRow from an update cursor (`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`) be quicker than inserting into another FC?

Comment: I haven't try it, but have my doubts. Deletion of 100,000 points takes ages in ArcGIS and yes again  a second or so in ArcView

Comment: I used your code, which was really good in terms of time. However, the results are missing the spatial reference. Is there is way to add spatial reference?

Comment: If it works for you please mark it as solved and ask separate question on defining projection

Comment: I double checked the results and found that many points having same x,y coordinates are still existing. It seems like the code doesn't delete all identical points. What might be the reason? I put the numbers into the excel and the IF function to test whether those x,y values are equal. The test show they are not equal, but the x,y values are the same as shown. How to fix this issue?

Comment: @TianxinLi you need to verify in ArcMap that the points are identical, not in Excel.

Comment: How many points in output?

Comment: About 1.6 million.

Comment: @Midavalo ♦. I know, but the runtime with ArcGIS was a problem for my problem.

Comment: a) You cannot put 1.6 million points in Excel b) Select area where you suspect duplicates, export points for this area and run delete duplicates. If no reduction, it means your points are not strictly duplicates Alternativel;y use xy tolerance

Comment: I believe you are right. The points might not be exactly identical, but in reality they should be. Is there a way to add the xy tolerance to the code you offered?

Comment: see updated solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46558/discussion-between-felixip-and-tianxin-li).

Comment: a set would work better than a dictionary in this case

Comment: Slow performance may be caused by 32-bit nature of arcgis desktop . If you try to use "delete identical" in 64-bit background processing envinronment (running in python script) - it may show better results (not tested).

Comment: @FelixIP. Your code works quite well for my question. Thanks.