# Merging/combining huge point (layer) data using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, merge, big-data

i have 2 point feature layer (file GDB), each layer have a lot of point feature (records with depth value), around 80.000.000-100.000.000 records/point. there are overlapping area between those layer (15-20%) and in the overlap area, the point are intersect perfectly (the points are overlap perfectly in overlap area).

i need to delete those points in the overlap area (1 of those layer) so when i overlay or merge both layer, no duplicate point feature.

i have several method :

1. merge those layer, use find identical and delete identical.  or
2. generate x-y in those layers, select the points in the overlap area , use select by location (intersect model) between 2 layers, then unselect 1 of the layer, and delete the points in other layer.

my problem is, both method makes my computer crash.
i have 64 GB ram, i7 proccessor, 32GB VGA that is a really great spec right.

so any better solution?

Comment: Have you tried to call the geoprocessing tools with background processing turned on, that run's in a 64 bit environment?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213602/the-fast-way-to-delete-many-duplicate-points/213608#213608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this on even a very modest spec computer I would use ArcPy to replicate the Librarian VISIT functionality from ArcInfo Workstation.

To do that use arcpy.da.SearchCursor to iterate an index layer (from Create Fishnet would be fine) and grab each geometry (@SHAPE) to Clip each feature class into multiple feature classes.  While processing each row in that SearchCursor, do your Geoprocessing tile-wise, and then after the SearchCursor completes merge your results back.

Comment: actually, i dont understand how to use arcpy, i only knows about tools and model builder on arcmap, and i dont understand either about librarian visit

Comment: The same approach could be taken using ModelBuilder and its iterators, but it would take much more to implement and would process much more slowly.